# Xamarin iOS Native Linking Error. Could not find file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I updated to the newest XCode recently and ever since I have been getting errors while building for iOS. The errors all look like:

```
 Error MT5209: Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: 'project directory/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone5.3-10.3.2/mtouch-cache/GoogleMaps'
```

There are 11 of them. Each one has a different final folder name:

- FirebaseAuth
- FirebaseAnalytics
- GoogleSymbolUtilities
- GoogleInterchangeUtilities
- FirebaseInstanceID
- FirebaseCore
- GoogleMapsCore
- GoogleMapsBase
- GooglePlaces
- GooglePlacePicker

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project directory and remove **obj** and **bin** folders. Then try to build again.

Comment: Ugh. I had a shitty day yesterday and apparently skipped this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my issue was funny. The app directory name had space. "App Name"

Just renamed the folder to be 1 word ("AppName") and it worked